# Need some good example of Cucumber+Java+selenium+TESTNG parallel execution with Extent report

Tags: cucumber-java, selenium-extent-report

Can someone help with example of 
Cucumber+Java+selenium+TESTNG parallel execution with Extent reporting.

Comment: Plenty of content is available on different blogs and web urls. Search and implement, in case there is any issue, ask it specifically. Its a broad topic to cover in one question.

Comment: I am facing issues while executing my framework on docker, the extent report doesnt save the screen capture on extent docker container

Comment: I would suggest to give try to [gherkin with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) and take full advantages of TestNG which has nice detailed [reporting](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html) as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use cucable-plugin which lets you execute multiple features in parallel. you can also execute multiple scenario outline examples in parallel using cucuable.
It is vast topic to explain here go to https://github.com/trivago/cucable-plugin#cucable-maven-plugin to explore more about parallel execution.
And for better reporting you can use cluecumber-report-plugin which generates combined html report by combining all json reports created by Runners.